# How can I disable the faded title text in the top panel?

Tags: panel, appmenu

So I'm new to Linux but am basically blown away by Ubuntu 12.04 and could definitely see this becoming my main desktop over time

One small annoyance for me is a tendency for the global menu on the top bar to partially over-write the text description of the active window in the top panel.

e.g. I focus on the "Ubuntu Software Centre" window which writes out that label in the leftmost corner of the top menu bar.  If I then move the cursor up to the top menu bar to access the "file menu", this will partially overwrite the window name leaving just "Ubuntu" visible.

This is a little slice of ugliness I don't want to see every day!  Much easier on the eye for me would be to display the active window name at the centre of the top panel, using some of that free space and then have the global menu stay where it is, just to the right of the app launcher.

I've found a solution to disable the global menu but I would prefer to keep it and instead move (or disable) the active window name in the top panel.

Any way to do this?

Comment: Oh well, I guess I'll just make do with disabling the global menu for now

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug that shows up in applications when the global menu is not fully integrated into the application.  For example, software center has a global menu however the close/minimise/maximise buttons still appear on the title bar instead of next to the global menu - example compare the Firefox global menu.

What happens is, the global menu text is drawn on the top bar, but the space where the buttons should be is not drawn, leaving part of the title text showing though.

Bug or feature?  I don't know but I can't find a launchpad bug that deals with this.  Maybe start a new bug report and see how it flies?  Chris.